# document on submit isn't submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button outside of the form that when pressed, submits my form. That form has an event on it for onSubmit that fires off and then just does some form checks, making sure fields are present. At the end of the form, I return true and nothing happens. Can't seem to figure this out. Appreciate the extra set of eyes. I did verify that that function is being called and makes it all the way past the checks, just nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
$(document).on('click','.but_addTask',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#addTaskForm').submit();
});

$(document).on('submit','#addTaskForm',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var description = $('#description').val();
    var dueDate = $('#dueDate').val();

    if(!$('.taskClientID').length){
        alert('Please add client(s) to task');
        $('#taskClientSearch').focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(description==""){
        alert("Please enter a description")
        $('#description').focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(!$('.taskAuditorID').length){
        alert('Please add owner(s) to task');
        $('#taskOwnersSearch').focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(dueDate==""){
        alert("Please enter a dueDate")
        $('#dueDate').focus();
        return false;
    }

    console.log('made it!');
    return true;

});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already called `e.preventDefault();` at the start of the callback, which suppresses the default behaviour of the event (in this case of course, that behaviour is to submit). By the time you return true it's too late.

If you remove that line, you should be ok.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: The OP probably doesn't need preventDefault on the button either (unless it is an anchor tag rather than button).

Comment: @AndyG that's true, if the button is outside the form as stated (and really is a button). Shame we can't see the HTML. I always find it bizarre that ppl ask questions closely relating to the GUI and then don't show the GUI,

Comment: sorry.. didn't think it was relevant... and it is an anchor link, not a button

Comment: @Damien no problem. So if it's an anchor you do need the preventDefault() on the click event.